# Get all objects in a list where a string parameter contains all strings in second list

Tags: c#, linq

I have a list of custom objects "CustomFile" - these holds various data as well as a "title" string parameter. The list itself is called "AllFiles".

I am displaying the "AllFiles" list to the user in a listbox (the users see only the "title" string of each "CustomFile" object).

I also have a search box where the user can enter a search string. He should then be shown a list of files filtered on the "title" parameter.

An example "AllFiles" list would look like this:

- [1] MS Excel documentation
- [2] MS Excel tutorial
- [3] MS Access documentation
- [4] MS Access tutorial
- [5] Google Chrome documentation
- [6] Google Product video for Chrome

I've used a LINQ query that selects all "CustomFiles" where "title" contains the search query.

So if the user searched for "documentation", he would see items 1, 3 and 5. But if he searched for "ms documentation" he would get no results because there's no exact match in "AllFiles" for "ms documentation".

Now I want to make the search a bit more flexible. When searching for "ms documentation", the user should see items 1 and 3. Likewise, if the user searched for "google chrome" he should see items 5 and 6, even though 6 does not contain the exact text "google chrome".

Basically I need to search the "AllFiles" list for objects where the "title" contains ALL of the words in the search query, no matter the order of the words.

So I split up the search query into a list of strings (listSearchWords). If the user searches for "google chrome", I have a list with entries [1] "google" and [2] "chrome". However now I'm stuck in what to do next.

The amount of words in the files and in the search query is of course dynamic, so I can't just do a "contains item 1 OR contains item 2". I need to somehow filter the "AllWords" list for objects where "title" contains all the strings from listSearchWords.

Thank you for any help.

***EDIT***

Through the accepted answer, I got it down to just two lines:

```
List<string> searchTerms = searchQuery.Text.Split(' ').ToList();
```

searchQuery is the string of search terms inputted by the user.

```
    var filteredObjects = AllObjects.Where
    (a => searchTerms.All(b => a.[string parameter on object].IndexOf
    (b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)).ToList(); 
    //AllObjects is a list of the custom objects. 
    //string parameter on object] is the string variable on the custom object that I'm filtering on.
```

Comment: [Enumerable.All<TSource>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb548541(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: It seems the All method just returns a bool on whether or not all elements of a sequence satisfy a certain condition. I've read and re-read the article you linked, but I don't entirely understand how to apply this to my problem.

Comment: Did you try the sample code in a console app?  The All method is in a Where method.  The outer Where method will select every item in the search items where a certain criteria is true.  The criteria is that the search item has to contain ALL of the search terms you have tokenised.  If I understand your question correctly, I really think this is  an appropriate solution.

Comment: Yeah I was having a bit of problems with understanding though. Linq syntax can get a bit complex imo when there's a lot of nested commands. Anyway I got it finally due to your code below. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use LINQ to phrase the query using your tokenised list of search terms.  Something like this:

```
searchItems.Where(a => searchTerms.All(a.Contains))
```

This effectively iterates through all of your search items and returns items where the search item contains EVERY search term.

The above is case sensitive, if you wanted it to be case insensitive you would have to try something like this:

```
searchItems.Where(a => searchTerms.All(b => a.IndexOf(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0));
```

**EDIT:**

Here is a complete working example:

```
namespace ConsoleApplication7
{
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var searchItems = new List<string> { "MS Excel documentation", "MS Excel tutorial", "MS Access documentation", "MS Access tutorial", "Google Chrome documentation", "Google Product video for Chrome" };
        var searchTerms = new List<string> { "google", "chrome" };

        var searchResults = searchItems.Where(a => searchTerms.All(b => a.IndexOf(b, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase) >= 0)).ToList();

        foreach (var searchResult in searchResults)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(searchResult);
        }

        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
}
```

Comment: This gives me an error message saying 'System.Collections.Generic.List<string>' does not contain a definition for 'All' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Enumerable.All<TSource>(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource>, System.Func<TSource,bool>)' has some invalid arguments.

Sorry if I'm missing something obvious here.

Comment: it is likely related to missing namespace imports.  I'll post a complete example, give me a minute.

Answer (score 0):

You can modify the sample code as needed.

```
 List<string> a = new List<string>();
        a.Add("[1] MS Excel documentation");
        a.Add("[2] MS Excel tutorial");
        a.Add("[3] MS Access documentation");
        a.Add("[4] MS Access tutorial");
        a.Add("[5] Google Chrome documentation");
        a.Add("[6] Google Product video for Chrome");
        var result = from item in a
                     let x = "MS"
                     let y = "documentation"
                     where item.Contains(x) && item.Contains(y)
                     select item;
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
```

Comment: `"ms documentation"` is a user input in run time, so it's not known in compile time. Which means your solution does not fit it.

Comment: @zerkms, you can modify it. Say `let x=args[0]` etc. Try it.

Comment: Omg, the input is **A STRING**: `"this is a list of search terms"`. Please be more careful and spend some extra time to re-read the question and my comments once again. Thank you.

Comment: I don't think this helps me out much, as the search terms are dynamic, meaning there can be any number of search terms, not just 2 like in your example. It might be possible to modify to be dynamic, but I unfortunately do not see how. Thanks though!

Comment: @MortenK, then you may rewrite an extension method of where clause by this idea, it is not hard. I may try it if I have time.

Answer (score 0):

If you write an extension method. It can achieve the goal.

```
 class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        List<string> a = new List<string>();
        a.Add("[1] MS Excel documentation");
        a.Add("[2] MS Excel tutorial");
        a.Add("[3] MS Access documentation");
        a.Add("[4] MS Access tutorial");
        a.Add("[5] Google Chrome documentation");
        a.Add("[6] Google Product video for Chrome");
        string search = "MS documentation";
        var result = a.WhereExtension(search);
        foreach (var item in result)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}
public static class MyExtensions
{
    public static List<string> WhereExtension(this List<string> source, string items)
    {
        var search = items.Split(' ');
        List<string> list = new List<string>();
        foreach (string item in source)
        {
            bool add = true;
            for (int i = 0; i < search.Count(); i++)
            {
                if (!item.Contains(search[i]))
                    add = false;
            }
            if (add == true)
                list.Add(item);
        }
        return list;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I got it down to just two lines though, using the accepted answer suggestion.